# uniqueness of the solution of heat equation in convolution form

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, partial-differential-equations

I wish show the solution expressed in the form
$$u(t,x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Phi_t(x-y)f(y)\,dy$$
is unique for any $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ (the space of rapidly decreasing functions in $\mathbb{R}$.)

Here, $u$ is a classical solution satisfies
Consider an equation on $\mathbb{R}$:
    \begin{align*}\tag{1}
  \begin{cases}
   \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,x)&=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}(t,x) \qquad t>0, x\in\mathbb{R}^d, \\
  u(0,x)&=f(x),\qquad x\in\mathbb{R}^n
  \end{cases} 
 \end{align*}

Here we start with assuming there exist two solutions, $u_1$ and $u_2$ both satisfies (1). Then I want to find the differential inequality for the function $W(t)=|u_2(t)-u_1(t)|=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|u_2(t,x)-u_1(t,x)|\,dx$ and the Gronwall inequality.

So I have
\begin{align*}
w(t)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|u_2(t)-u_1(t)|\,dx\\
\Longrightarrow [w(t)]^2&=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}|u_2(t)-u_1(t)|\,dx\right)^2
\end{align*}

Then $$\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}F^2(t)=F(t)\frac{d}{dt}F(t),$$ now I am lost...any help appreciated.

Comment: What is that $S$?

Comment: please see edited

Answer (score 2):

Uniqueness does not hold for the heat equation. An example was constructed by Tychonov. You can find it in chapter 7 of Fritz John's classical book [Partial Differential Equations](https://books.google.es/books?id=Mz0mBQAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

There is uniqueness in the class of functions bounded by a quadratic exponential. There is also uniqueness in the class of non-negative functions (Widder's theorem.)

Comment: I wish to complete what I was doing in the sense of the 2nd part of your answer...hope you could help

Comment: The standard proof uses the maximum principle.

Comment: yes, it is in evans book and in everywhere...but I want something in ODE sense, like the uniqueness of weak solution...something similar to bottom p.187 to top p.188...https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch6.pdf

Comment: You can apply the $L^2$ estimate on the ball of radius $R$ and let $R\to\infty$. You will need to justify that the boundary terms allow for this.

Comment: Does the equality $|u_2(t)-u_1(t)|=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|u_2(t,x)-u_1(t,x)|\,dx$ hold?

Comment: I shall correct my last comment. That was not quite what I want. What I wish to show is to show the uniqueness of $u(t,x)$ in convolution form, i.e. the integral $u(t,x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Phi_t(x-y)f(y)\,dy$. Similar to prop 1.2.3 in page 9 http://www.math.unipr.it/~lunardi/LectureNotes/I-Sem2005.pdf

Comment: The above reference assumes $A$ is a bounded operator. Here $A=\Delta$, which is unbounded. You should read section 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{t}u(t,x) &=&\partial _{x}^{2}u(t,x) \\
u(0,x) &=&f(x)
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
v(t,x) &=&u_{1}(t,x)-u_{2}(t,x) \\
\partial _{t}v(t,x) &=&\partial _{x}^{2}v(t,x) \\
v(0,x) &=&0
\end{eqnarray*}
For the Fourier transform $\tilde{v}(t,k)$we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{t}\tilde{v}(t,k) &=&-k^{2}\tilde{v}(t,k) \\
\tilde{v}(0,k) &=&0
\end{eqnarray*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{v}(t,k)=\exp [-k^{2}t]\tilde{v}(0,k)=0
\end{equation*}
so $v(t,x)$ must vanish.

Comment: You did not mention that.